# "Delete partition" option grayed out in disk management

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

When I went to disk management on windows 7, I tried to delete the volume and then the deleted volume went to "free space". For some reason, when I then tried to delete the "free space" volume, the option is grayed out.

[image: 1]

How can I make the option available again?

Comment: you already deleted it, why do it again? Not logical. Now make it a new simple volume, then resize or merge it.

Answer (score 1):

Free Space = Unallocated Space = Unpartitioned Space

If you're looking at resizing your other existing partitions to fill in that gap, I'd probably make a backup to be safe.  I'd also recommend not touching the first 16 GB partition or the System Reserved as that could cause issues.

Personally, I'd use something like [GParted](http://gparted.org/) off a live CD to do partition changes.  Doing it in Windows bothers me for some reason.

**Edit**:  Using GParted may get you around not being able to resize partitions through Windows.  I don't think Windows will let you resize a partition that's currently in use (C: in this case).  Not sure why it won't let you adjust F:

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete free space, as that's what it is, an open section of the disk. To get rid of it either make a new partition or extend a current partition to fill it.

Comment: But the "extend volume" option is also grayed out on all drives

Comment: Ah yes, the windows partition manager does have problems deleting Logical partitions (I'm guessing that's what it was), use free Partition Wizard to Resize it into any empty space whether (Primary) Unallocated or (Logical) Free Space. Rightclick C to Resize, slide right grey border all the way to the right, OK, Apply.                                       

Heres the link to it : http://www.partitionwizard.com/download.html